# Select rows that don't have a corresponding join in join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two SQL tables - customer and widget. There's a join table, customers_widgets between them, that has two columns (customer_id and widget_id)

Is there a way I can select all the customers that aren't joined to a widget? So they have an id that doesn't appear in the customer_id column on the join table?

Comment: SELECT * FROM customer c where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM customer_widgets cw JOIN widgets w ON w.widget_id = cw.widget_id WHERE cw.customer_id = c.customer_id);

Answer (score 3):

In general I've found `NOT IN` to be expensive and slow, but your mileage may vary on different RDBMS.

The two alternatives that I most often use are:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM customers_widgets
                 WHERE customers_widgets.customer_id = customer.customer_id 
               )
```

And...

```
SELECT
    customer.*
FROM
    customer
LEFT JOIN
    customers_widgets
        ON  customers_widgets.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE
    customer_widgets.customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Your observation about `IN(...)` is completely wrong. Given NOT-NULL-ability, `NOT EXISTS()` and `NOT IN(...)` are equivalent. (`NOT IN()` is uglyer, but that is still a matter of taste)

Comment: @wildplasser - You can't possibly make that statement about my experiences.  I specifically stated that this is what I have experienced, but then caveat it by saying that YMMV on different RDBMS. Cases in point are that on MySQL the `NOT IN` performance degrades rapidly as the list grows, and Redshift is poor at Both `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` but fast with the anti-semi-join.  Different RDBMS *DO* vary in behaviour, and my *personal* experience has been that `NOT IN` has never been *faster* than the alternatives, but *often* has been *slower*.  That's across about a dozen enterprise platforms.

Comment: And note; `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` often do not generate the same plans.  Thus while the resulting logic / functionality is largely the same, they are not synonyms

Comment: For Postgres, they do generate the same plan. IF the affected field is not NULL-able, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id 
                          FROM customers_widgets)
```

Comment: A bit dangerous if customers_widgets.customer_id is nullable.

Comment: @jarlh Yes this is correct, but on the other hand `customers_widgets.customer_id` being nullable in a junction table is an indication of flawed database design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OUTER JOIN` for this:

```
Select    C.*
From      customer         C
Left Join customer_widgets W  On  C.customer_id = W.customer_id
Where     W.customer_id Is Null
```